# Is it possible to limits google places to one or two places like restaurants or coffeeshops?

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, location, geofencing

I'm building an app in swift that can filter places to one or two types of locations e.g restaurants or coffeeshops is that possible and how its done ?

The app fetch data only from these places.

Answer (score 1):

**YES** you can search via Types in the google places like in this example

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Mexican+Restaurant&sensor=true&location=40.846,-73.938&radius=20&key=yourKeyHere

**Explanation:**

This will give you result in the radius of 20km with all types of restaurants in Mexico. you can also check this documentation for a lot of different variation.

https://developers.google.com/places/?csw=1#PlaceSearchResults